# Using earlier and later as adjectives

Tags: usage

Can you use *earlier* and *later* as adjectives? Here is a conversation I overheard this morning:

> A: I was able to do two paintings yesterday.
>
> B: Me, too. But the earlier one I had to re-do, because Professor C hated it.

Can you use *earlier* and *later* like this? I guess the person was using *earlier* as a short version of "the one I painted earlier," but I'm not sure if this usage is correct.

Comment: If I were speaking of something more directly related to time, this would sound okay to me. (Ex. *"I was supposed to have two meetings today, but I had to cancel the earlier one so I would have time to prepare for the later one."*) Meetings are inherently time-related; paintings aren't. So I know that this *sounds* wrong to me, but I can't guarantee it breaks any sort of rule (and I would understand it if I heard it, just as you did.) So I shall wait and see what others have to say about this!

Comment: *Earlier* and *later* are two different words, and what applies to one may not apply to the other.  As a result, it doesn't make sense to write "the person was using *earlier/later*".  They weren't; they were only using *earlier*.  (It's still fine to ask about both *earlier* and *later*, of course!)

Answer (score 4):

*Early* and *earlier* (and also *late/later*) can all be used as adjectives, but whilst *earlier* and *later* are usually used to describe the **relative occurance of an event to another** (perhaps implied) event, *early* and *late* are used to describe the **absolute occurance of an event on a (often implied) timeline**.

For example, when considering a collection of paintings:

> This is a nice painting, but I prefer your **earlier** paintings

This statement states that the author prefers paintings that were created *before* the current painting. This contrasts with the statement:

> This is a nice painting, but I prefer your **early** paintings

This statement on the other hand states that the author prefers paintings that were painted early on the unspecified but implied timeline of the artist's entire career.

Similarly, suppose the theatre has showings at 8 AM, 11 AM, 2:00 PM, 5 PM, 10PM, 11 PM and midnight. Then

> I wasn't able to get tickets for the 11PM showing, but I got tickets for a **later** showing

In this case, the tickets procured must be for the midnight showing, since this is the only showing that is later than 11PM.

On the other hand,

> I wasn't able to get the tickets for the 11PM showing, but I got tickets for a **late** showing

In this case, the first clause is merely descriptive; tickets could not be obtained for the 11PM showing. The second clause stands alone stating that tickets *could* be obtained for a late showing, and hence the tickets might be for the midnight one OR the 10PM showing, since both are objectively "late showings". The 10PM showing is a late showing even though it is earlier than the 11PM showing.

**When no separate comparative event is provided** *earlier* and *later* mean the same as *early* and *late*, but are just less idiomatic; assuming no other context, the following two sentences are equivalent:

> I prefer Mozart's earlier works
>
> I prefer Mozart's early works (preferable)

Be aware that *late* as an adjective also has the meaning *dead* that the adjective *later* does not have:

> The late Oscar Wilde was a very witty man.
>
> (X) The later Oscar Wilde was a very witty man

And finally there are certain idioms where the choice of "late/later" and "early/earlier" is fixed. In these cases, you should not substitute late for later or early for earlier (or vv):

> The early bird catches the worm!
>
> (X) The earlier bird catches the worm!

Answer (score 1):

It's OK. *Early* and *late* may act as either adjectives or adverbs.

> The early bird catches the worm, because it rises early, before the other birds get a chance.
>   We call it The Late Show, because it plays late at night.

Comment: Hmm. Do you think there's a bit of an idiomatic preference to when these *sound* right or wrong? To me personally, both of your examples sound fine, but the one in the OP's question sounds strange. And I wouldn't refer to my firstborn as my *earlier child*, but I would refer to a meeting I cancelled this morning as an *earlier meeting*. What do you think?

Comment: @WendiKidd Well, your firstborn is of course more conventionally referred to as your "older" (or "elder") child. But I wrote my dissertation on the "early" plays of Bernard Shaw (it's right there in the subtitle), so using "early" with works of art sounds just fine to me.

Comment: @StoneyB: I'm fine with an artist talking about his *early work* - so he can have *earlier* (and *later*) paintings. But for things produced *on the same day*, I'd much prefer plain old *first*. And can you really toggle *early/earlier* so casually?

Comment: @WendiKidd: If I was talking about two paintings painted on the same day, I would probably distinguish them by using _first_, not _earlier_: _But the **first** one I had to re-do, because Professor C hated it._ I think that's maybe why it sounds odd. But _earlier_ still works as an adjective: _Of the Paleozoic and the Mesozoic eras, the Mesozoic is the **earlier** era_.

Comment: @J.R. Agreed; I think there are some cases where *earlier* clearly works well as an adjective, but the OP's case in particular doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Clearly you do not realize that once a work has left the hands of a True Artist it is relegated forthwith to the Deep Past ;) Perhaps this was a painter of landscapes, for whom Early and Late in the day are quite different challenges.

Comment: StoneyB: Yeah, right! But it's always possible the first one was done late in the morning, and the second one was done early afternoon. It's all relative (but on this particular usage I'm solidly behind @Wendikidd! :)

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what could be objectionable or unidiomatic about the OP's example.  Interesting discussion!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use *earlier* and *later* as adjectives; just that, the usage has to be correct. I think  ***But I had to re-do the earlier one, because Professor C hated it*** sounds more correct.